# How to show custom block when "view block" is empty Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, block, drupal-8, drupal-views

I have a view block of content type "Career". I want to show a custom block when the "Career" is empty.
I tried to add in "NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR" a field (Global: Rendered entity - Custom block (Global: Rendered entity - Custom block) and I typed the id of the custom block.
- The content of custom block is shown in the view block, but I don't know why when I reload the page, I got nothing in place of view block.
What should I do?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Either your custom block provides no content or you found a bug, so you should probably report it.

Comment: @MilanG The custom block contains textual content. The problem is the content of custom text is shown in the Career View Block . I will add a picture for that.

Comment: Try it with default theme (Bartik).

Comment: @MilanG I will do that

Comment: The preview feature on Views does not run everything through the theme engine the same way it will be ran on the frontend of the website. Can you add a screenshot of the no results behavior when the view is added to a page?

Comment: @IsaiahNixon. I found the problem. The section of "view-empty " in view-view.html.twig is empty. I added {{ empty }} to this section and it works. Thank you very much.